# SEO management in Google Search Console for a non-english version of a website

Tags: seo, google-search-console, canonical-url, local-seo, internationalization

I have a website `example.com` made with docusaurus. Initially, the website was in English. Several months ago, I added the Chinese version with `i18n`. All the chinese pages are under `zh-CN`; so a page like `https://www.example.com/zh-CN/docs/a-page` displays well contents in Chinese.

However, by inspecting in Google Search Console, I just realized that lots of chinese pages are NOT indexed in Google.

At the moment, we have `example.com` as a domain property to Google Search Console. I'm thinking whether we need to add a specific domain property to Google Search Console for a better SEO of the Chinese version of the website.

I tried to add `https://www.example.com/zh-CN` without trialing slash as URL prefix as shown in the following screenshot. And Google Search Console adds automatically a trailing slash (i.e., `https://www.example.com/zh-CN/`) when creating the domain property.

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Should I add such a specific domain property like above to Google Search Console for a better SEO of the Chinese version of the website?
2. Google Search Console enforces the URL prefix to be `https://www.example.com/zh-CN/` with trailing slash, does it mean that we should make canonical URLs have trailing slash (currently, we make canonical URLs without trailing slash)?

Comment: If these changes are new, maybe you just have to wait. In any case, you can always manually request indexing for e.g. `https://www.example.com/zh-CN/docs/a-page` and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Search Console will look at all the URLs branching from the root. I'm not sure that adding a specific URL within the same domain would achieve anything.